# Mysql empty query in php - what do I get? Resource ID?

Tags: php, mysql, resources

I want to check whether my query is empty (has no rows). What is the best way of hecking it?

And what do I get in the following "$result" and "$row" (this is how I am aiming to solve this - `if($result)` or maybe using `if($row)` means that it is not empty. Any better suggestions?

Thanks.

```
       $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1= '$var1'
                              AND column2 IN ('no','nein','nope')
                              AND timestamp BETWEEN '$date' AND NOW()"); 
       $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test this.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1= '$var1'
                          AND column2 IN ('no','nein','nope')
                          AND timestamp BETWEEN '$date' AND NOW()"); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
   echo $row['column name'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `mysql_num_rows($result)` get the number of rows, or you could see if `$row === false`;

`$row` will be the first row of the recordset OR `false` if the query has no results.
`$result` will be a recordset resource if the query succeeded of `false` if it had an error.

If you are this early in the project and/or just learning please consider switching to the new DB interface [`PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). At the least use [`Mysqli`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)... the mysql extension youre using now is a bit outdated. It works, and sometimes its even required in legacy apps/sites, but it should be avoided if possible.

Comment: which extension are you talking about that is outdatedd? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: [`ext\mysql`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) is outdated, which is the one you used in your initial post. [This may help you understand](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Which_PHP_Driver_for_MySQL_should_I_use). It should be noted that that document places `mysqli` over `PDO` in its recommendation because `mysqli` supports a couple of MySQL specific features PDO does not. I however place more importance on the unified API PDO provides across different DB's and in writing DB agnostic code. I also find the PDO API much easier to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`mysql_num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) to get the row count.

$result will always be of type Resource if your query didn't fail.